Error estimate for almost Beta function
let $\lambda>0$ and $\lambda\to \infty$, $0<\alpha\to 1$, how to give the error estimate to
$$\int_0^{\arctan \lambda} \sin ^2 \theta \cos ^{4 \alpha-2} \theta\, \mathrm{d} \theta=B\left(\frac{3}{2}, 2 \alpha-\frac{1}{2}\right)+\text{small term},$$where $ B(a, b)=\int_0^1 t^{a-1}(1-t)^{b-1} \mathrm{~d} t$ is the Beta function. My question is give a estimate of the small term. Welcome any comments.

$$\int_0^{\arctan \lambda} \sin ^2 \theta \cos ^{4 \alpha-2} \theta, \mathrm{d} \theta=\frac12B\left(\frac{3}{2}, 2 \alpha-\frac{1}{2}\right)-\frac1{4\alpha-1}\frac1{\lambda^{4\alpha-1}}+\frac12\frac{4\alpha+2}{4\alpha+1}\frac1{\lambda^{4\alpha+1}}+O\Big(\frac1{\lambda^{4\alpha+3}}\Big)$$

Can you show me some details of this calculation? Thanks!

Using the substitution $\tan\theta =x$
$$I=\int_0^\lambda\frac{x^2}{(1+x^2)^{2\alpha+1}}dx=\frac12\int_0^{\lambda^2}\frac t{(1+t)^{2\alpha+1}}dt\overset{x=\frac1{1+t}}=\frac12\int_{\frac1{1+\lambda^2}}^1\sqrt{1-x},x^{2\alpha-\frac32}dx$$
$$=\frac12\int_0^1\sqrt{1-x},x^{2\alpha-\frac32}dx-\frac12\int_0^{\frac1{1+\lambda^2}}\sqrt{1-x},x^{2\alpha-\frac32}dx$$
$$=\frac12B\Big(\frac32;2\alpha-\frac12\Big)-\frac12\int_0^{\frac1{1+\lambda^2}}\Big(1-\frac x2+\frac{x^2}8-...\Big)x^{2\alpha-\frac32}dx$$
